# jQuery Custom Scroll bars - are they SEO Friendly?

Tags: jquery, css, seo, scrollbar, customization

I've been trying to research this but with no success, I'm gonna ask it fresh here. If I made a Custom jQuery Scroll bar like http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Will this make the scrollable content SEO unfriendly? 
Will search engines be able to crawl and read the content even though Jquery is involved with the look and feel of the scroll?

If it's not SEO friendly then its pointless in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, really? What makes you think scrollbars have any sort of impact on SEO...?

Comment: ... Because Jquery is involved ...

Comment: This *is* utterly pointless, but it has nothing to do with SEO. As Jack says, search engine crawlers don't care about visual effect stuff like that. People style scrollbars to make them look "cool", but they just end up being ugly and difficult to use. Yes, Apple does it in iOS, but on that platform, they're the native scrollbars and everyone expects them. That's not the case on Windows (among other operating systems), so you should not force your kewl scrollbars on Windows users. The scrollbars that the browser provides automatically are perfectly adequate, and probably superior.

Comment: Its not pointless because there's lots of reasons to style scroll bars and I don't need to explain why. Regarding my question, there's no need to bombard it or make sarky comments - I genuinely didn't know and what do you do when you don't know? Ask! Hence why the awesome website stack overflow was developed - to help people who would like to ask! I don't ask questions because I'm bored!

Comment: Whoa. Who said any of that? I have no idea if you're bored or not, and yes, Stack Overflow is for asking questions. No one has voted to close this one as being off topic. I have no idea what you mean by "bombard it". Leaving a comment is not "bombarding" your question. And there's nothing "snarky" about my comment. It's my well-reasoned opinion. You're free to disagree, but saying "it's not pointless because there's lots of reasons to [do it]" is not an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't have any impact on your SEO.  A crawler isn't going to be looking at any of that.

Comment: How confident are you on this (just to make extra sure)? Have you proved it before? For some reason I feel it will create a "hurdle" for crawlers and they will "battle" to read the information. Otherwise its just the answer I hoped I'd get!!